# Azure VPN - have no connection to VNET

Tags: azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I created a virtual network gateway on the only vnet i have. My idea is to be able to connect from the internet to the virtual machines on the network. The VPN works well authenticates by AD correctly.

It gives me the IP of the pool address that I configured in the "point-to-site" correctly.

Once connected I do not have access to any machine on the network. No ping no telnet

Am I skipping a step or do I have to do something else? The VM firewall is disabled. And the network security group of the VMs has the VNet-Vnet allowed. Also between the vms there is no communication problem

What is even weirder is that if I connect to an azure virtual machine and ping my notebook that connects to the VPN, ping responds. On the other hand, from the notebook to the virtual one, it does not respond

Answer (score 0):

**Here are the few step the needs addressed for Azure Point-to-Site VPN with Azure AD Authentication**

**Step1:** Create a Virtual Network

**Step 2:** Create a Virtual Network Gateway and select Vnet the above you have created.

**Step 3:** Give the admin consent to the Azure VPN application using this link

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=41b23e61-6c1e-4545-b367-cd054e0ed4b4&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fportal.azure.com&nonce=1234&prompt=admin_consent

**Step 4:** Take the tenant id of azure ad. (Azure AD- >Properties)

**Step5:** Select Azure Gateway and go the point-to-site configuration.

**Step 6:** Configure the point to site. You can keep the same address pool which I have kept below.

[image]

Where Tenant:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/Tenant_ID/

Where Audience:  41b23e61-6c1e-4545-b367-cd054e0ed4b4(default)

Issuer: https://sts.windows.net/Tenant_ID/

**Step 7**: Once fill the details save it, download the VPN client, and extract the file.

**Step 8**: download the Azure VPN client using this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/azure-vpn-client-preview/9np355qt2sqb?rtc=2&activetab=pivot:overviewtab. And open it

[image]

**Step 9**: Once open select import and add azurevpnconfig.xml file from the above extracted file.

[image]

**Step 10**: Save it and connected with your Azure account.

Now you connected with your Azure Vnet using point to site VPN.
[image]

**Step 11**: Create your VM in the same VNET.

**Step 12**: ping your VM from your notebook. (I have used my private Ip to ping here)

[image]

The below picture is for ping from VM to my notebook.
[image]

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/openvpn-azure-ad-tenant